# Как проверить строку на дату?

Tags: python, datetime

Мне нужно проверить строку на дату.

Дата может быть в двух форматах: '%d.%m' и '%d.%m.%Y'

Пробовал:

```
d = '09.01.2020'
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%d.%m') or datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%d.%m.%Y')
except:
    print('неверный формат')
```

Вывод:

```
неверный формат
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Исходя из вашего кода, вы отправляете в `except` все ошибки, включая ту, которая возникает, из-за того, что вы не импортировали библиотеку `datetime`

Предложу такой вариант решения:

```
import datetime

d = '09.01.2020'
if len(d.split('.')) == 3:
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%d.%m.%Y')
        print('Ok')
            
    except Exception:
        print('неверный формат')
else:
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%d.%m')
        print('Ok')
            
    except Exception:
        print('неверный формат')
```

Вывод:

```
Ok
```

Я написал в `except` значение `Exception`, чтобы не отлавливать каждую по отдельности ошибку, а все сразу. Вы можете указать конкретные ошибки и уже с ними взаимодействовать.